# Увеличить дату на один день

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

Есть web-сайт java, на форму прикрутил datepicker jQuery.
Для выборки с БД нужно сравнивать 2 даты, а точнее, есть переход с одного дня на другой, например есть некая смена 1 (её время с 22-00 01.01.2016 по 7-00 02.01.2016).

На форме для отображения отчета могут выбрать совершенно любую дату и год, но если это смена 1 то нужно вместо текущей даты использовать дату следующего дня.

Как это правильно реализовать? Смены определяю так:

```
if (gang.equals("1")){time_start = "22:00:00"; time_end = "7:00:00";}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы получить значение даты в js на сутки больше (делаю вывод из темы вопроса), чем имеющееся значение, достаточно сделать так:

```
// date - какая-то имеющаяся дата
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1) //если дата на стыке месяца, все равно корректно рассчитается браузером
```

В Java, насколько могу судить по документации, должно сработать:

```
//date - инстанс java.util.Calendar
date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

В Oracle, если используется тип DATE, достаточно сделать `date + 1`, что даст дату следующую за `date`.

В целом, подобные вещи, как мне кажется, лучше делать в бд при запросе отчета.

Т.к. в бд все равно должны быть идентификаторы смен, либо данные о том, какая смена работает ночью, а так же, для построения отчета, необходимо отправить в процедуру какой-либо идентификатор группы, то логично в процедуре построения отчета сделать проверку, что если смена работает на стыке дат - проверять на сутки больше (грубо говоря).

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"});      date.setDate(date.getDate() +1)
});</script> Так ?

Comment: Хорошо если лучше делать выберать все через бд, как мне определить начальную дату и конечную ? поделитесь пожалуйста

Comment: в приведенном в комментарии коде, вы не проверяете, что это первая смена, а так же нигде не получаете дату в переменную date.

Comment: Спасибо за мысль, решил проблему запросом БД.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Дата текущего дня.
const today = new Date();

// Добавляем 3 дня, например.
today.setDate(today.getDate() + 3);

// Устанавливаем значения для полей ввода.
window['input_1031906_1'].valueAsDate = today;

// Другие способы вывода.
window['input_1031906_2'].value = today.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU');
window['input_1031906_3'].value = today.toISOString().slice(0, 16);
```

```html
<input id="input_1031906_1" type="date" value="" />

<p>Другие способы вывода</p>

<input id="input_1031906_2" type="text" value="" />
<input id="input_1031906_3" type="datetime-local" value="" />
```